# Best Practice for localizable string casing

Tags: ios, localization

As I am localizing my app, I have discovered many duplicates due to casing.

For example, I want to use "done" and "Done". Should I have two seperate key values to be translated, or should I use "Done" and lowercase it?

Do some languages have different words if they are Uppercased or not?

What are the pros/cons of using one key rather than two.

Comment: IMO (which is what this question is seeking), how you approach this is subjective to what languages you wish to support. A simple example is to go to Google Translate and put 'done' and 'Done' in against Russian. Using done gives you сделанный while Done gives Готово. I don't speak Russian, so I do not know if that is valid, but the potential exists across languages to have unique translations. On the other hand, other languages do not have the concept of capitalization and will be unaffected.

Comment: Yes -- I think the real question is.. Do some languages have different words if they are Uppercased or not? And if not, what are the pros/cons of using one key rather than two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you shouldn't be thinking of individual words being localized in isolation. You should be think about UI elements being localized, and intents being localized. So, instead of "done" what you mean is "the label for a button a user presses to indicate they are done." This may translate differently from "a label indicating that a task is complete." They may capitalize differently, but they may be completely different words, or different conjugations/declensions/genders depending on the grammar.

This is why the comment field of `NSLocalizedString` is so critical. If it's empty, or just repeats the key, then you're likely approaching localization incorrectly.

Just as the most basic example, considering asking a translator to translate the word "fire." In English, we use the same word in "a roaring fire" and "to fire a gun." You can't translate that word without context; and with context, you can indicate whether you want it capitalized if appropriate.

All that said, sometimes you have exactly the same meaning for two different UI elements and you absolutely want to use the same translation for them both to avoid confusion, but in one case you want a different capitalization for aesthetic reasons. In that case, you should translate whichever is convenient (usually the lowercase version), and then use `localizedCapitalized` or `localizedUppercase` to adjust it. I use this often for making buttons all-caps.

But you're correct that sometimes capitalizing a word can change its meaning, which comes back to commenting your localization phrases so the translator knows which spelling to use. And if your meaning and context are not precisely the same, you probably will want two keys.

To your underlying question, English has words that mean different things depending on how their capitalized (see CodeBender's link), but other languages also have very different rules. German capitalizes all nouns, but does not capitalize some adjectives that English does capitalize. (Compare "the American car" vs "das amerikanische Auto"). Russian has very different rules for capitalization than English (Russia is capitalized, Россия, but Russian is not, русский). Russian also typically only capitalizes the first letter in certain phrases where English would capitalize every word (book titles, for instance). So...it's complicated. And making it feel natural to a native speaker generally requires a human translator who knows what they're translating.

Comment: The analogy of using "fire" for two different meanings helped me understand more clearly. I will be using the UI elements as the key now. Thanks.

Comment: I would actually think about not tying it to UI element. Rather context. The reason for this is you may have 2 different UI elements that need to the same exact word/sentence based on context. So does this mean you re-use the UI context key? Or create a new one for the the different UI element? If you opt for this, you may want to treat the UI element keys as an alias to the actual key. FWIW, I've worked on highly localized products and built the infrastructure for them. So my comment is based on the hard knocks of error.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, you are wanting to know if the target language(s) you wish to translate against will contain [Capitonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitonym).

> A capitonym is a word that changes its meaning (and sometimes
>   pronunciation) when it is capitalized

Without knowing much about your specific situation, this is impossible to answer.

However, assuming you can perform a check against the target languages and confirm that you will not be impacted by this, then I would recommend you utilize a single style across your words. This benefits you in a few ways:

- If you are paying for your translations, then you save $
- By eliminating duplicates, you reduce the risk of conflicting translations (some translating firms may farm out the words across individuals)
- You decouple the word from how it appears in your app, allowing you the freedom to adjust capitalization at a later date if need be or for other apps in the future